# How to route the custom URL path using nginx server?

Tags: nginx

I am building the angular app and want to route the URL to http://localhost/sample/AngularApp/. but don't want to give the entire URL in the browser. I will give the only localhost. In angular, while building the dist we are using the command `ng build --base-href=/sample/AngularApp/` and created the folder structure /sample/AngularApp in Nginx mentioned path `/usr/share/nginx/html`.so while accessing the application still, we are giving the entire path in browser. so, How could I resolve this issue and how to configure that path in nginx.conf file to autoroute the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with standard configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html/YourAngularApp/dist;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

This gives opportunity to serve other files (if found) or fall back to index.html located at the project's root.

Now, if you have everything in place you should build your project with

```
ng build --base-href=/
```

`--base-href=/` can be omitted as it defaults to `/`. Please have a look at Angular docs about using `--base-href` and `--deploy-url`

Comment: Hi Szczad. The configuration which you provided is the default one. I will create a sample and AngularApp folders inside `/var/www/html` and then copy the content of dist inside that. now Can I mention /Sample/AngularApp/ instead of index.html?

Comment: I would rather change the `root` value to the root directory where `index.html` is located. i.e. `root /var/www/html/sample/AngularApp/;`

Comment: yeah, I changed the root path as you suggested. still, it seems to be asking URL while accessing the browser. we have to autoroute the path

Comment: Have you reloaded the Nginx daemon? `nginx -s reload`

Comment: Yes, we reloaded the Nginx daemon.

Comment: I've rewritten the exalmple with whole `server` directive. This should work.

Comment: url is not showing that routing path in browser. Is there any alternative way for this?

Comment: I've went through Angular docs. Have you tried building it with `ng build --base-href=/`? Base href defines the base location of your application in the web server so every time you visit `/` at your server you're being redirected to the full webpage by your browser (because it's hardcoded in your application).